# How can I assign the keyboard shortcut ⌘x to the command move to trash?

Tags: osx-lion

In the Finder in Leopard I used to have the command "move to trash" associated with the keyboard shortcut ⌘x which was very handy because you could input the command with one hand. Moreover on the keyboard x is near to c, s and a which are other shortcuts often used in Finder.

Now in Lion the command "move to trash" is associated to ⌘ ⌫ but I don't like it. How can I assign the keyboard shortcut ⌘x to the command "move to trash"?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the shortcuts of most menu bar items in the Keyboard preference pane:

[image]

Note that pressing ⌘X while renaming a file will move it to trash. (As pressing ⌘⌫ does now.)